# Mac : How to enter the full directory path in a save As Dialog?

Tags: macos

Suppose I am editing a document/file in an app like MS office, text editor or emacs, etc and I want to save the document in a particular directory.

On Windows/Linux, using my aliases, etc, I would quickly navigate to the directory where it should be saved and copy the path of the directory to clipboard and then paste the directory path into the "save as" dialog.

On Mac, there is no field where I can paste the full directory path in the "Save as" Dialog. If Windows and Linux provide for a way to do, why don't I find the same in the mac. In the mac, I have to navigate through the mouse from the favourite directories or the filesystem and that takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shortcut

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

opens the "Go To Folder" sheet.
(There is an even shorter way: just type a forward slash if the save menu has opened. Thanks to Calrion for commenting this.)

[image]

[Source and good explanation](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/31/go-to-folder-useful-mac-os-x-keyboard-shortcut/)

Comment: Typing a single forward slash (as one would to begin an absolute path) will generally also display the go to folder sheet. The forward slash will be included in the text box, so you can just keep typing.